# What does recent research tell us about how English sounded in Shakespeare's time?

Tags: discussion, pronunciation

I am interested in finding a present-day pronunciation that I could point to as close to that which was spoken in Shakespeare's era, much as if I were directing one of Shakespeare's plays and were advising performers. I am not seeking information about vocabulary, syntax, or grammar.

Comment: Check out the transcriptions in Görlach's _Early Modern English_. From my ear, they sound a lot like a strong modern Irish accent.

Comment: However interesting this post may potentially be, it is possibly too broad for our format. You might try asking for a phonetic guide to Elizabethan English, but that will probably end up in meta, where other similar posts usually get migrated to.

Comment: Pose this question on YouTube. There's a wealth of videos addressing it.

Comment: An answer here (a reference for Elizabethan pronunciation, would be a very welcome addition to our ELU meta reference guide.

Comment: [Here's a Wikipedia on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare_in_Original_Pronunciation).

Comment: There has been plenty of research on this topic, as well as many popular articles. (For example: https://www.bbc.com/culture/article/20180207-how-americans-preserved-british-english or https://www.npr.org/2012/03/24/149160526/shakespeares-accent-how-did-the-bard-really-sound) Have you tried looking for information yourself?

Answer (score 4):

You could certainly do worse than consulting David Crystal's [*The Oxford Dictionary of Original Shakespearean Pronunciation.*](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-oxford-dictionary-of-original-shakespearean-pronunciation-9780199668427?cc=gb&lang=en&)

The book has [a companion website](https://global.oup.com/booksites/content/9780199668427/)  where you can listen to recordings and stuff like that.